# Is there any way to simplify Outlook macro installation?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2007-addin

I've created Outlook 2007 macro, which add additional item to mail context menu (`Sub Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay`). Now I would like to allow other users to use this macro. How can I simplify macro installation for them?

Now I have to ask them to run Macro editor and copy-paste the macro code.

Probably, I can convert that to some Outlook addin / msi?

Comment: `Probably, I can convert that to some Outlook addin / msi?` That is exactly what I would do, and use an installer (like Inno Setup) to create a program to install the addin on each computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to deliver VBA code in a "correct" way to other users. Microsoft itself recommends your approach (copy-paste), because that is the only way to preserve what other users have possibly inserted in their outlook code file (VBAProject.otm).

I propose that you do some studying for yourself before asking beginner questions. There are plenty of resources available which can be found easily. I recommend you to start with [OutlookCode](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=37) , where a very good choice of articles will led you to understand how to go on.